# What process to execute on closing command prompt

Tags: node.js

I'm running my nodejs scripts from in a command prompt window. As I do want to have the script execute a kind of CLEAN UP on closing the program I need to call a function right before closing.

If the script is stopped using CTRL-Z this is already happening.
But whenever the command prompt window is closed directly, this clean up isn't executed.

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() { cleaningup() });
```

where cleaningup is the function needs to be called. I'm running on a windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux CTRL-Z *suspend*s the process, so no cleanup is executed, since the process is not terminated.
If you mean CTRL-C, yes, it produces the BREAK signal: it interrupts the program execution, and terminates it.
The code you did post is correct to execute a cleaning up function when CTRL-C (SIGINT) is detected.

*Note: if you're OS is not Linux, please specify it in your question...*